# Uniqueness of orthogonal "permuting" matrices

Tags: matrices, svd, orthogonal-matrices, similar-matrices, permutation-matrices

Let $
0<\sigma_1<\sigma_2$, and set $\Sigma=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$. Define
$
P=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
$
and suppose that $P_1\Sigma P_2=P\Sigma P=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_2,\sigma_1)$ where $P_1,P_2 
\in \operatorname{O}(2)$ are real orthogonal matrices.

> **Question:**  Is $P_1=P$ (and then $P_2=P$) or $P_1=PR$ (and then $P_2=RP$) where $R$ is diagonal?

If not, can we characterize all the such orthogonal pairs $(P_1,P_2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $P_1\Sigma P_2=P\Sigma P$ are two singular value decompositions of the same matrix with two distinct singular values. Thus the matrix's left or right singular spaces are one-dimensional and $P_1=PD_1$ and $P_2=D_2P$ for some diagonal orthogonal matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$. As $\Sigma$ is invertible and $PD_1\Sigma D_2P=P_1\Sigma P_2=P\Sigma P$, we have $D_1D_2=I$. Hence $D_1=D_2=$ some diagonal matrix $D$ whose diagonal entries are $\pm1$, and $P_1=PD,\,P_2=DP$.

Answer (score 0):

Just take, $
P_1=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\\ a & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$
$
P_2=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \bar a  \\\ \bar a & 0\end{pmatrix}
= P_1^* $
Where $|a|^2=1$
For example, $P_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \ -1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} =P_2 $
And,
$P_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 
 1 \\\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} $
$P_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} $
Also can be taken in field $\mathbb{C} $.

Also, all possible pairs are, $(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -a \\\ -a & 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\bar a \\\ -\bar a & 0\end{pmatrix})
$

$(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -a \\\ a & 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \bar a \\\ -\bar a & 0\end{pmatrix}) 
$

$(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\\ -a & 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\bar a \\\ \bar a & 0\end{pmatrix})
$
Where, $|a|^2=1 $

Comment: Nota that I assumed that the $P_i$ are orthogonal.

Comment: Please note, $|a|^2=1$

Comment: All your examples are included in my question. For instance $P_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 
 1 \\\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=PR.$ The question was whether there exist other solutions. Also, note that I assume that the $P_i$ are real matrices.